# Controller.Url.HttpRouteUrl() generates bad Querystring with %amp

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a method in controller helper class to populate Model. I need to pass URL to model.
I generate URL like this

```
var url = Controller.Url.HttpRouteUrl("SomeRoute", new { id = 1, dateFrom = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1), dateTo = DateTime.Now });
```

however, the URL I get is something like this

```
/SomeRoute?id=1 &amp ;dateFrom=06%2F09%2F2016 18:43:28 &amp ;dateTo=06%2F09%2F2017 18:43:28
```

and in controller method of`SomeRoute()` I get parameters `amp:dateFrom` and `amp:dateTo` instead of `dateFrom` and `dateTo`. only first parameter is generated correclty. is it a bug ? how can I avoid this ugly url generation?

Comment: Can you post some context to how you are calling this code? How you are calling `Controller.Url.HttpRouteUrl` is probably going to be pretty key to finding your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try in action:

```
var url = Url.RouteUrl("SomeRoute",
    new { id = 1, dateFrom = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1), dateTo = DateTime.Now })
return View(url);
```

In view:

```
@Html.Raw(Model)
```

Or you can put it directly to view:

```
@Html.Raw(Url.RouteUrl("SomeRoute",
    new { id = 1, dateFrom = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1), dateTo = DateTime.Now }))
```

Comment: same thing with Url.RouteUrl method :(

Comment: I had problem on View side :) I was assigning @Model.url to javascript variable like this var someUrl = '@Model.url' now its fixed like this var someUrl = '@Html.Raw(Model.url)';  thanks :)

Comment: Glad to have been of help

Answer (score 0):

it is html encoding issue, you need to tell it is html string, you can use

`MvcHtmlString.Create(url);`

It should work.